# Checked use Core Data in new project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data

When I created my Xcode project i checked the checkbox "use Core Data" because I thought I was going to use that. Now however it turns out I never used Core Data and would like to disable it. My project is way to big to just simply create a new project and leave the checkbox unchecked.
Does anyone know what methodes and files I need to delete in order to have a project without Core Data? I think some project settings need to be changed as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a new empty project and find out. Must of the methods will be in your App delegate. You also have to remove the Data model (.xcdatamodel) file from your project